# When can you move a Spirit Companion?

Tags: dnd-4e, shaman

Can the spirit companion move anytime the shaman takes a move action, or does it need to be a move action where the shaman moves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the Q&A section in: [linky](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/21836709/Spirited_Away_A_Shaman_Handbook)

> It moves up to your move speed when you take a move action

Thus, as it explicitly notes a "move action" it only moves when you take a move action. However, it can be any move action. Take a look at the [Dragon Article](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/387/387_Shaman_Basics.pdf) they reference for more details. Unfortunately, the wording here is pretty unambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

"When you take a move action, you can also move the spirit a number of squares equal to your speed."

So, not a separate action, just any time the shaman moves, the spirit companion may also move.